# Free memory detection tools for Delphi for QA

Tags: delphi, memory-leaks

I have found some tools that can help the developers to find out the memory leaks like FastMM4. But can a QA person use it to determine memory leaks after we take a build? or is there any tool available that can aid a QA person to find out memory leaks then it would be great.

currently what we follow is like run the application note down the memory usage and perform some tasks and then check out the memory usage and if we find out a huge difference then we star narrowing down. Is there any tool which will do it automatically

Comment: Recent Delphi versions include AQTime in the box. What delphi version are you using?

Comment: @WarrenP: I am using Delphi XE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lots of functionality in FastMM4 can be enabled or disabled depending on a presence of FastMM_FullDebugMode.dll in system. This way you can have only one build, where leak detection will be enabled by copying FastMM_FullDebugMode.dll to program folder. Similar functionality you can achieve by using ShareMem unit together with different versions of BorlndMM.dll. In this case you can compile FastMM4 to BorlndMM.dll with any options you want.

Answer (score 2):

Your QA testers can equally use FastMM to detect memory leaks. You just need to give them a build which enables memory leak detection.

Comment: Does it involves any code changes or just an compiler setting?

Comment: You make the changes in the FastMM include file

Answer (score 0):

SouceGuard is a lite and effective leakproof and bug reporting tool in Delphi.
It was formerly known as UMLD.